# Toggling FontAwesome fa-rotate-90 causes page flickering on Mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, macos, google-chrome

This problem only appears when using Chrome on Mac. I failed to replicate this issue with any browser on Windows. My code is below:

```
<div class="service-item">
  <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
</div>

$('.service-item').hover (function() {
    $(this).children("i").toggleClass("fa-rotate-90");
    return false;
});
```

Whenever I hover the `.service-item` container the page keeps "flickering". Any ideas of what's happening?

Comment: did you figure this out? I seem to have the same problem

Comment: scratch that - it actually only seems to happen when Developer Tools is active

Comment: It actually only happened when I previewed the page from another website's iframe, so I left it as it is